# Kafka Connect BigQuery Sink Connector requests incorrect subject names from the Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

While trying to use [confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/) on our Kafka (Avro) events, I run into the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic domain.user to Avro: 
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:125)
[...]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro key schema version for id 619
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject 'domain.user-key' not found.; error code: 40401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:295)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:355)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:440)
[...]
```

And yes, there is no subject `domain.user-key` in the schema registry:

```sh
curl --silent -X GET http://avro-schema-registry.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:8081/subjects | jq . | grep "domain\.user"
```

```
[...]
  "domain.user-com.acme.message_schema.type.domain.key.DefaultKey",
  "domain.user-com.acme.message_schema.domain.user.Key",
[...]
```

How can I make the connector use the right subject names?

My `properties/connector.properties` (I'm using the [quickstart](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/tree/master/kcbq-connector/quickstart) folder.) looks as follows:

```
[...]
topics=domain.user
sanitizeTopics=true
autoUpdateSchemas=true
autoCreateTables=true
allowNewBigQueryFields=true
[...]
```

In the end, I want to use `topics.regex=domain.*` instead of `topics=domain.user` to capture all our domain-event topics, but with this I get the same type of error (just for a different subject).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy` & `value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy` to be `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really tried but did not find this solution anywhere. Thanks again. It works perfectly. :)