# Kafka Connect BigQuery Sink Connector requests non-existing key-subject names from the Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

This is a follow-up question to that one: [Kafka Connect BigQuery Sink Connector requests incorrect subject names from the Schema Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372061/)

While trying to use [confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/) on our Kafka (Avro) events, I run into the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic domain.rating.annotated to Avro: 
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:125)
[...]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro key schema version for id 619
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject 'domain.rating.annotated-com.acme.message_schema.type.domain.key.DefaultKey' not found.; error code: 40401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:295)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:355)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:440)
[...]
```

The subjects that do exist are

```sh
curl --silent -X GET http://avro-schema-registry.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:8081/subjects | jq .
```

```
[...]
  "domain.rating.annotated-com.acme.message_schema.domain.rating.annotated.Key",
  "domain.rating.annotated-com.acme.message_schema.domain.rating.annotated.RatingTranslated",
[...]
```

Why is it looking for `...DefaultKey` instead, and how can I make it do the right thing?

My `properties/standalone.properties` (I'm using the [quickstart](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/tree/master/kcbq-connector/quickstart) folder.) looks as follows:

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://avro-schema-registry.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://avro-schema-registry.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:8081
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I need the following:

```
key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
```

With this, it works. :)

I'm really struggling with navigating the documentation. Sorry for the superfluous question.